# VBA : Fast method to compare two columns in two different sheets and copy value from 2nd sheet next to the respective cell in sheet 1

Tags: vba, performance, excel, loops

First of all, I apologize in advance if my English is not perfect, I'll try to do my best to explain my need.

So basically, I have an excel file with 2 sheets named "Balance" and "Balance_MAJ".

It looks like this (just a little sample) : ["Balance" & "Balance_MAJ"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaF1k.png)

What I need is to compare **Column D of "Balance"** with **Column D of "Balance_MAJ"** in order to update **Column F of "Balance"** using values from **Column G of "Balance_MAJ"**.

In fact, Columns D of these 2 sheets contain the same informations but not in the same order. So, I have to make 2 loops to compare these 2 columns and each time it matches, I will get the respective value in Column G of "Balance_MAJ" and I will put it in the respective cell in Column F of "Balance".

Something like that : [What I need to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B02Ez.jpg)

The problem is that my entire dataset contains a large quantity of data (about 12 000 rows today, it may contain way more rows in the future). I used 2 methods and in both cases it worked perfectely, but it was really slow (about 1mn50sec with the first method and 47sec with the second method).

**First method (1mn50sec) :**

```
`Sub MAJ_Balance()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim lastRow_Balance As Long
Dim lastRow_BalanceMAJ As Long
Dim stNow As Date

stNow = Now

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastRow_Balance = Sheets("Balance").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
lastRow_BalanceMAJ = Sheets("Balance_MAJ").Cells(Rows.Count, 
"D").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 5 To lastRow_Balance
      For j = 5 To lastRow_BalanceMAJ 
        If Sheets("Balance").Cells(i, "D").Value = 
           Sheets("Balance_MAJ").Cells(j, "D").Value Then
           Sheets("Balance").Cells(i, "F").Value = 
           Sheets("Balance_MAJ").Cells(j, "G").Value
        End If
      Next j
    Next i

MsgBox (DateDiff("s", stNow, Now))

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub`
```

**Second method (47sec) :**

```
`Sub MAJ_Balance()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim v As Variant
Dim lastRow_Balance As Long
Dim lastRow_BalanceMAJ As Long
Dim stNow As Date

stNow = Now

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastRow_Balance = Sheets("Balance").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
lastRow_BalanceMAJ = Sheets("Balance_MAJ").Cells(Rows.Count, 
"D").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 5 To lastRow_Balance
      With Sheets("Balance").Cells(i, "D")
      v = .Value
      For j = 5 To lastRow_BalanceMAJ 
        If v = Sheets("Balance_MAJ").Cells(j, "D").Value Then
        Sheets("Balance").Cells(i, "F").Value = 
        Sheets("Balance_MAJ").Cells(j, "G").Value
        End If
      Next j
      End With
    Next i

MsgBox (DateDiff("s", stNow, Now))

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub`
```

Do you have any idea for code optimization ? **What is the fastest method to do that ?**

I thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Instead of repeatedly accessing the worksheet, do all your work in VBA arrays.  You will probably see about a ten-fold increase in speed.  See Chip Pearson's discussion on [VBA arrays and Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) for more information.  This question is better suited for Code Review

Comment: Why does this need VBA? This can be accomplished with a [VLOOKUP formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Comment: X2 on arrays and Code Review (since it's working code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested two additional methods, one using VLOOKUP and one using the suggested Arrays.  I used your provided sample setup with data copied down to row 28,676 on both sheets.  Here is the code for the two methods and my speed test macro as well:

```
Sub VLOOKUP_Method()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsBal As Worksheet
    Dim wsMAJ As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsBal = wb.Sheets("Balance")
    Set wsMAJ = wb.Sheets("Balance_MAJ")

    With wsBal.Range("F5", wsBal.Cells(wsBal.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
        .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(D" & .Row & ",'" & wsMAJ.Name & "'!D:G,4,FALSE)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub

Sub ARRAY_Method()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsBal As Worksheet
    Dim wsMAJ As Worksheet
    Dim aBalData As Variant
    Dim aMAJData As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsBal = wb.Sheets("Balance")
    Set wsMAJ = wb.Sheets("Balance_MAJ")

    aBalData = wsBal.Range("B4").CurrentRegion.Value
    aMAJData = wsMAJ.Range("B4").CurrentRegion.Value

    For i = LBound(aBalData, 1) To UBound(aBalData, 1)
        For j = LBound(aMAJData, 1) To UBound(aMAJData, 1)
            If aBalData(i, 3) = aMAJData(j, 3) Then
                aBalData(i, 5) = aMAJData(j, 6)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    wsBal.Range("B4").Resize(UBound(aBalData, 1), UBound(aBalData, 2)).Value = aBalData

End Sub

Sub SpeedTests()

    Dim dTimer As Double
    Dim aResults(1 To 100, 1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    j = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(aResults, 1)
        j = j + 1
        dTimer = Timer
        VLOOKUP_Method
        aResults(j, 1) = Timer - dTimer
    Next i

    j = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(aResults, 1)
        j = j + 1
        dTimer = Timer
        ARRAY_Method
        aResults(j, 2) = Timer - dTimer
    Next i

    Sheets("Speed_Results").Range("A2").Resize(UBound(aResults, 1), UBound(aResults, 2)).Value = aResults

End Sub
```

Here are the results of the speed tests on my system.  VLOOKUP was faster by a factor of about 2.5

[image]

Comment: Wow Vlookup method executes almost instantly, this is exactly what I needed ! Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Last question, how can I do now if I want to copy the whole row of "Balance_MAJ" (and place this row at the end of "Balance") each time an element exists in Column D of "Balance_MAJ" but not in Column D of "Balance" ? Thank you